# preg_match make sure first character in string is uppercase or lowercase letter

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

can someone show me the regex for this preg_match. I want to make sure first letter in string is nothing but a letter, either uppercase or lowercase. thanks. I found this, but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
var_dump(preg_match("^/[A-Za-z]+/", $search_terms ));
```

The line above returns false, every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this, for your regex :

```
/^[A-Za-z]/
```

- Begins with : `^`
- One character that is a letter : `[A-Za-z]`

The `^` symbol should be at the beginning of the regex, but **inside its delimiters** ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`"^/[A-Za-z]+/"` should be `"/^[A-Za-z]+/"`